# MomentJs: Having to import each moment locale for all possible languages?

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

After having some problems getting momentjs localized date formats to work properly, I happened upon a thread that correctly stated that the target moment locale resource would have to be imported, e.g., for French (fr):

```
import 'moment/locale/fr';
```

and indeed this works. However this would would imply that the module I'm coding using moment would have to explicitly import every moment locale module? If so, this implies that the code would have to be touched every time a new locale is supported? This would't seem right.

I'm hoping for a better solution for this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Usually the list of supported application languages is limited, so it's unreasonable to load all available Moment locales because of increased footprint.

Moment package contains prebundled locales for this purpose. E.g:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/min/locales';
```

Or:

```
import moment from 'moment/min/moment-with-locales';
```

Comment: @PetertheRussian What did exactly not work? The suggested solution is workable with current Moment version. If you have a problem that can be replicated, consider asking a new question that contains a way to reproduce your problem.

Comment: When i tried it first I it did not work and then i fixed my issue;
Then when I import them all together 'moment/min/moment-with-locales' and start my server (react/redux) i got an error from webPack
Finally i resolved the issue by using the above imports 
I need to wait a little bit before i can revote

Comment: @PetertheRussian Glad you sorted this out. You likely won't be able to change the vote on SO because it's already been settled.